# Filtro com primeiro item de um ManyToMany Django

Tags: django

Tenho isso no meu template:

```
{% for j in jobs %}
    <tbody>
        {% if j.background.all.0.active == False %}
        ...
```

Dai estou precisando fazer um filter na view semelhante a isso.

Tentei

```
jobs = jobs.filter(background__first__active=False)
```

Mas eu sei que está completamente errado.

A saber background é um ManyToMany que contém um campo chamado active, mas eu só quero pegar o first item.

Como eu faço esse filtro?

Comment: Uma das opções que existem além de MeuModel.objects.all() e MeuModel.objects.filter(), é o MeuModel.objects.first().
Se você quer o primeiro elemento de um queryset, você pode usar no template
{{ j.background.first }}. Só que isso pega o primeiro item de um queryset, não entendi exatamente a utilidade desse filtro que você fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veja: https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first

você pode tentar algo como:

```
jobs = jobs.filter(background__active=False).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

Corroborando a resposta do Regis, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
jobs = Jobs.objects.filter(background_active=False)[0]
```